Wearables and Trackers Question on Steps or Settings Modification
History
I don't know how many site visitors read user profiles, so I'm posting this little bit before I get to my actual question, so that the question makes sense.  I was born with Cerebral Palsy.  If WikiPedia isn't your preferred site for medical conditions, feel free to search your preferred medical advice site.  They'll all tell you pretty much the same thing.  That said, I'm classified as a spastic tri-plegic (tight muscles affecting 3 limbs).  In my case, it's both legs and my right arm. Read On....
Question
Since I cannot walk, and am confined to an electric chair, I'd like to find a wearable or health tracker compatible with a Google Pixel 9 XL.  I recently switched from a Samsung Galaxy A-315.  With that I had a Samsung Galaxy Watch 6 that I never setup.  Not only do I feel I've wasted about $400 US, as that watch is just sitting, but I'd love to use that watch or Google's version as a health monitoring tool since I'm nearly 50. I'm stuck at an impasse here.  It was my impression that the main monitoring functions were done through the step counter.

Since I can't walk, and sit in a chair 10 to 12 hours a day, the watch behaves as follows:

The Heart monitor incorrectly reports me as idle (i.e., I sit too much.  While this is true, I'm still active).
The step counter stays at zero, even though I roll nearly a mile a day while working.
I wasn't able to "test" the other apps as I kind of gave up when I realized the devices are tracking something I can't do.  The only one that may work properly is the sleep monitor, but again not tested.


Do any readers know of any wearables or tracker type devices that are specifically made for disabled people.

Every time I think about Googling Electric chair + Wearables, I cringe at the thought of how many results I might get for something like a Continuous Glucose Monitor and give up for fear of wading through useless results
Is there a way to tell the wearable device that you cannot walk, so that you're monitored differently?  I don't think this is specific to only Android based wearables but since I have an Android based phone, I thought I would post here.




You are looking for something specialised, so you will not find it mainstream.  The step-counter is called that because that is what it is designed for and tested for.  The business logic on each device for this will be a secret and not open for modification.  Otherwise there would be mass panic and cries of "does not work".

Unfortunately, this is what I was afraid of.  I'm going to mark this as the Answer, although other Answers will be read if posted.  I've reached out to the disability support team @ Google via my GMail account, and they've routed my ticket to the "Dedicated Support Team" and I'm waiting for a reply
